# How to install SSIS in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, installation, sql-server-2014

I already have SQL Server 2014 on my computer. I don't remember installing SSIS.

How can I check if I do have it if not how can I add it ?

Thank you

Comment: try checking sql server configuration manager to see if ssis is installed

Answer (score 2):

Check your Windows Services for a service named "SQL Server Integration Services 12.0".

If you find you need to add just run the SQL Installer and choose "Add features to existing instance" and mark the option "Integration Services"

Answer (score 1):

You could launch the `SQL server configuration manager` for your installed SQL server to check whether there is SSIS installed, if not you could start the SQL Server Setup, choose `Add feature` to install `SQL Server Integration Service`

And if you need to modify any SSIS packages, you could install `Visual Studio` plus `SSDT` (Data tools), make sure the compatibility issue, for example, packages designed in VS2013 can only be deployed to SQL Server 2014, VS2012 to SQL server 2012, etc.

Comment: How do you launch the configuration manager?

Comment: OK, found that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of way to check if SSIS is installed. I personally like to use the SQL Server Configuration Manager. If you see the `SQL Server Integration Services` service in the configuration manager then you have SSIS running on your machine. If you need to add SSIS to the machine you can follow the steps in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/add-features-to-an-instance-of-sql-server-2016-setup).

[image]

Comment: I don't . just checked . I need to install it I guess.

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: Follow the directions in the article I linked to. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/add-features-to-an-instance-of-sql-server-2016-setup

Comment: How do you launch the configuration manager?

Comment: @Dodecaphone https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017